# Why submit form data to the site will appear to be a busy business

Tags: python-3.x, request

I want to climb to a website from China.first log in

```
values = {'__VIEWSTATE': 'dDw1MjQ2ODMxNzY7Oz5pEk/dqkpVDLoTnyvjiXNSAh3jVg==',
      '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': '701681CC',
      'username': 'xxxxx',
      'password': 'xxxxxx',
      'RadioButtonList1': 'xx',
      'Button1': 'xx'}
headers = {
'User_Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36'}
r=requests.Session()
url='http://jwgl.yctu.edu.cn/(1sngbonbcqry2355lvzasi55)/default_ysdx.aspx'
s=r.post(url,data=values)
```

and i print the `s.text` the output

```
<script>window.open('xs_main.aspx?xh=14263319','_parent');</script>
......
```

I think I've logged in.so i try to get some information about myself.

```
url='xxxx'
r.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

This is a study of the results of the page,but it doesn't show any important information.I do the same operation by chrome.Next,i want to get my grades this semester,form data was post to web.

```
form_data={'__VIEWSTATE':'xxxxxx',
         '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'DB0F94E3',
         'ddlXN':'',
         'ddlXQ':'',
         'Button1':'semester'}
r.headers.update({'referer':'xxxxxxxx')
print(r.post(url,data=form_data).text)
```

the output

```
sorry,Network busy
```

i can not find my error operation.